# Why does android wifi direct behaves in unreliable way?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am creating a chat application using wifi direct in which i am connecting to the group owner  automatically from all the devices but once i send invitation to the group owner then on GO's device no popup shows(Confirmation dialog of accept and cancel the connection) a lots of time.Sometimes it shows and sometimes it doesn't.I am not getting  what is wrong with this.Once connection established all works fine but for establishing connection its big problem. Does anybody have any idea about this?